# how bind event dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i bind dynamically event into a n element created? i'll try to this code, but the element use always the last state of the variable i (i=8), have i a problem with the scope?

```
        console.log('add all children');

        var myloc = window.location.href + "jquery";
        var jquerySample = 8;

        for (i = 1; i <= jquerySample; i++) {

            var element=jQuery('<div/>', {
                id: 'subitemElement' + i,
                href: myloc + "/test_jQ_" + i,
                class: 'subitem',
                rel: 'external',
                text: "test_jQ_" + i,
                click: function(num) {
                    console.log("subitem jquery click");

                    window.location = myloc + "/test_jQ_" + num;
                }(i)
            });
            element.appendTo('#itemJQUERY');

            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Comment: are you calling the click function right after it be declared? what are you expecting with that?

Comment: I expected to every element that I created is already connected with url changed according to the index of the for loop, obviously wrong; I have to deepen the study of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#itemJQUERY').on('click','.subitem',function(){
    window.location = $(this).data('url');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lvyoh7u/1/

Comment: why you bind the event outside the declarition of the object? is a best-practice?

Comment: This way it's just bound to the single parent element and listens to clicks that bubble up from the subitems. This is also used to work with objects that are not yet created at the time of binding the event. Read more about "Direct and delegated events" at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be more successful with the following code:

```
console.log('add all children');

    var myloc = window.location.href + "jquery";
    var jquerySample = 8;

    for (i = 1; i <= jquerySample; i++) {
        var element = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr(
                {
                    id: 'subitemElement' + i,
                    rel: 'external'
                })
            .data(
                {
                    url: myloc + "/test_jQ_" + i,   
                })
            .text('test_jQ_' + i)
            .addClass('subitem')
            .click(function(e)
                   {
                       window.location = $(this).data('url');
                   });

        element.appendTo('#itemJQUERY');
    }
```

A div doesn't have an attribute called href. Save it as data.

See jsfiddle here: [A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lvyoh7u/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myloc = window.location.href + "jquery";
    var jquerySample = 8;

    for (i = 1; i <= jquerySample; i++) {

        var element=jQuery('<div/>', {
            id: 'subitemElement' + i,
            class: 'configureClass'
            href: myloc + "/test_jQ_" + i,
            class: 'subitem',
            rel: 'external',
            text: "test_jQ_" + i
        });
        element.appendTo('#itemJQUERY');

        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //if Jquery - 1.7
    $(".configureClass").live(click,function(){
        window.location = myloc + $(this).text();
    });
    //if Jquery - > 1.9
$(".configureClass").on(click,function(){
            window.location = myloc + $(this).text();
        });
```

Above code will work!!
Don't bind any JS events in the html. Make it separate.

Happy coding!!

Comment: Do not use `.live()` as it has been removed from jQuery. Version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9 - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thank, Still using 1.7 in my project.